Use generating function to count the number of cycles of length k in the complete graph $K_n$
Let $c_{n,k}$ denote the number of cycles of length $k$ in the complete graph $K_n$. How should we obtain a closed formula for the bivariate generating series
$$C(x,y) = \sum_{n,k \geq 0} c_{n,k} \frac{x^ny^k}{n!}.$$
I am totally stuck on this problem since it seems like there wasn't any interesting recursive structure on complete graph $\mathcal{K}$, we can think of it as
$$\mathcal{K} \equiv \mathcal{E}[\mathcal{X}],$$
then we have $$K(x) = \exp(x),$$
but how to incorporate $y$ into our bivariate generating series $C(x,y)$?

I think you should start by finding a formula for $c_{n,k}$ (not using EGF methods, just using basic combinatorics).

The formula for $c_{n,k}$ is $\binom{n}{k}(k-1)!\frac{1}{2k}$. But I think it's not helpful here.

I solved it using exponential generating functions! First we need to understand which class/structure we are counting on. To do this, we take $y=1$ in bivariate generating series,
$$ M(x) := C(x,1) = \sum_{n,k\geq 0}c_{n,k}\frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{n,k}\right) \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
So $M_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}c_{n,k}$ is the coefficients of e.g.s. for class $\mathcal{M}$, with only one cycle with length $k=3, 4, \dots, k$. So we can have the recursive structure
$$\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal{H} * \mathcal{E}[\mathcal{X}]$$
where $\mathcal{H}$ denote the class of cycles,
with $$\mathcal{H}(x) = \sum_{n\geq 3} \frac{(n-1)!}{2}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$M(x) = H(x)\exp(x) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1}{1-x}) - \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{4}\right)\exp(x).$$
Then corporate $y$ into the recursive relation, we have
$$C(x,y) = H(xy)\exp(x) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1}{1-xy}) - \frac{xy}{2} - \frac{(xy)^2}{4}\right)\exp(x).$$

Start by evaluating $c_{n,k}$.
$$
c_{n,k}=\begin{cases}
0 & k\in \{0,1,2\}\text{ or }n<k,\\
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot 2k} & k\ge 3\text{ and }n\ge k.
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
C(x,y)
&=\sum_{k\ge 0}{y^k} \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{c_{n,k}}{n!}x^n\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 3}{y^k} \sum_{n\ge k}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n!\cdot 2k}x^n\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k\ge 3}\frac{x^ky^k}k\sum_{n\ge k}\frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k\ge 3}\frac{x^ky^k}ke^x\\
&=e^x\left(-\frac{xy}2-\frac{x^2y^2}4+\frac12\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{x^ky^k}k\right)\\
&=e^x\left(-\frac{xy}2-\frac{x^2y^2}4-\frac12\log(1-xy)\right).
\end{align} 
$$

Thanks for the hard work! I finally got the same answer as yours using exponential generating series. I also posted my method down there.
